# Detect a white object with hole in image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.1

So I have videos, at first it's black with little white pixel here and there.
Then the white object appear and grow untill it reaches stability.

Once it's stable it occupie around 50% of the picture.

Here it's at the bottom but it could be at the top, at a side, at a corner.
Only constant is that in the end it will occupy a large portion of the picture.

How could I detect that?

I tried a hough circle detection but with no success.

for now I'm calculating the percent of non-black pixel in the image (more than 30% trigger detection) but it's slow as hell (2 for loop and a if with a counter).

[image: star approach]

ps : this is a ship approching a star when exiting hyperspace, useless colors where removed, the star surface is continuously changing, so the black holes in the white changes position over time.

## Edit :

My current solution :

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
idxs = np.any(gray != 0, axis=1) # index of rows with at least one non zero value
grayNoZeroLine = gray[idxs, :] # selection of the wanted rows
print idxs

if len(grayNoZeroLine)>200:
    print 'star detected'
```

it's fast, however I can't know where the star is in the screen using this detection method, turn out it's going to be important since I need to adjust the course and avoid it.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to achieve? Do you just want to know if a circle is present in the image, or do you also want to know where it is, how big, etc?

Comment: I want to detect when the star appear, so I guess detecting a circle even thought I just have a demie circle.note that the 2nd and 3th does not always appear. sometime it's 1st, 4th and the rest.

Comment: I can think of two easy ways to make your search faster: 1. Use a binary search to determine when the star is visible and when not. 2. Short circuit on >70% of pixels black.

Comment: Depending on the scope of the search you might also want to switch language, python is quite slow compared to e.g. C++.

Comment: I already coded 80% of what I need, plus I code in python everyday, c++ date back from high school. I'm going to stay with python :p